# Apply SVM on LDA in python

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, svm, topic-model, lda

hope someone kindly put time here,

my approach is like this:
TFIDF -> LDA -> SVM

I am using LDA to extract topics. I want to do topic modelling and use the topics as features to do document classification.

I know that I have to send the feature vector to SVM,
but my question is that how can I make this feature vector to send to svm?
Is featureValue here is the probability assigned to each word?
My question is kind of the step 3 in the below link that I dont know how to do it

[svm on lda](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138352/is-this-a-correct-way-to-do-document-classification-using-topic-modeling)

but in this link there is no implementation, that is just explanation.

Many thanks for your time:)

Comment: 1), Ignore the tfidf part, you cannot use tfidf in lda, lda takes only term counts; 2), Feed the document-topic distribution vector that you get from lda, to your svm classifier. They are your feature vector. Simples.

Comment: @Blue482,
May I ask you to leave the comment here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/21947/apply-svm-on-lda I create this post just with email as guest and had not signed up, so I can not put comment as guest, I mean for commenting there is no option of comment as guest at all even with that email https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/21947/apply-svm-on-lda

Answer (score 1):

Following your code in your other thread:

```
# Use tf (raw term count) features for LDA.
print("Extracting tf features for LDA...")
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                                max_features=n_features,
                                stop_words='english')
t0 = time()
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_samples)
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

print("Topic modelling with LDA...")
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=n_topics, max_iter=5,
                                learning_method='online',
                                learning_offset=50.,
                                random_state=0)

lda_x = lda.fit_transform(tf)
# so lda_x is your doc-topic distribution that you can use for feature vector to your SVM model.
# lda.components_ is your topic-word distribution.
```

Hope this helps!